# How does slice indexing work in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Suppose we have an array

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12]])
```

Now I have below

```
row_r1 = a[1, :]
row_r2 = a[1:2, :]

print(row_r1.shape)
print(row_r2.shape)
```

I don't understand why row_r1.shape is (4,) and row_r2.shape is (1,4)

Shouldn't their shape all equal to (4,)?

Comment: when you specify a range, rather than a single number, it returns that range as an axis. If the range 'happens to be' of size 1, it doen't change the fact that you asked for a slice (in that dimension) rather than a single element (which would remove the dimension. Hope it is clear

Comment: Documentation is clear.  Indexing with a scalar reduces a dimension.  Slices don't.  Question - how does list indexing work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like to think of it this way.   The first way `row[1, :]`, states go get me all values on row 1 like this:

[image]

Returning:
`array([5, 6, 7, 8])`

shape

`(4,)` Four values in a numpy array.

Where as the second `row[1:2, :]`, states go get me a slice of data between index 1 and index 2:

[image]

Returning:

`array([[5, 6, 7, 8]])`   *Note: the double brackets*

shape

`(1,4)`  Four values in on one row in a np.array.

Answer (score 0):

Their shapes are different because they aren't the same thing. You can verify by printing them:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12]])

row_r1 = a[1, :]
row_r2 = a[1:2, :]

print("{} is shape {}".format(row_r1, row_r1.shape))
print("{} is shape {}".format(row_r2, row_r2.shape))
```

Yields:

```
[5 6 7 8] is shape (4,)
[[5 6 7 8]] is shape (1, 4)
```

This is because indexing will return an element, whereas slicing will return an array. You can however manipulate them to be the same thing using the `.resize()` function available to numpy arrays.
The code:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12]])

row_r1 = a[1, :]
row_r2 = a[1:2, :]

print("{} is shape {}".format(row_r1, row_r1.shape))
print("{} is shape {}".format(row_r2, row_r2.shape))
# Now resize row_r1 to be the same shape
row_r1.resize((1, 4))
print("{} is shape {}".format(row_r1, row_r1.shape))
print("{} is shape {}".format(row_r2, row_r2.shape))
```

Yields

```
[5 6 7 8] is shape (4,)
[[5 6 7 8]] is shape (1, 4)
[[5 6 7 8]] is shape (1, 4)
[[5 6 7 8]] is shape (1, 4)
```

Showing that you are in fact now dealing with the same shaped object. Hope this helps clear it up!