# Understanding the slice notation in mini batch gradient descent

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

There are many answers on ways to implement mini batch in a neural network, but I wanted clarification on the notation of slicing.
A simple example;

```
mini_batch_size = 2
#so total number of mini batches should be 2,2,1
arr = np.array([[1, 3, 5, 7], [2, 4, 6, 8], [9,10,11,12], [13,14,15,16], [17,18,19,20])
num_complete_minibatches = np.floor(len(arr) / mini_batch_size)

for k in range (0, int(num_complete_minibatches)):
    mini_batch = result2[k * mini_batch_size:(k+1) * mini_batch_size, :]
    mini_batches.append(mini_batch)

if len(result2) % mini_batch_size != 0:
    end = (len(result2) - mini_batch_size) * np.floor(len(result2) / mini_batch_size)
    mini_batch = result2[int(num_complete_minibatches) * mini_batch_size:  , :]
    mini_batches.append(mini_batch)
```

What does the `k * mini_batch_size:(k+1) * mini_batch_size`  in the for loop actually mean?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does slice indexing work in numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55581540/how-does-slice-indexing-work-in-numpy-array)

Comment: It doesn’t, it’s unclear on why we are multiplying the slice

Comment: What do you mean multiplying the slice? That's just a multiplication for calculating the index... Would it be clearer if it was `i = k * mini_batch_size ; j = (k+1) * mini_batch_size ; mini_batch = result2[i:j, :]`?

Comment: That makes more sense. Thank you!

Comment: Think of a simpler example with lists. Doing `[1, 2, 3][5 * 3 -14]` is just the same as doing `[1, 2, 3][1]`