# Can someone please explain what this statement does to the image? image = image[60:-25, 0:, 0:]

Tags: python-3.x, crop

I'm trying to crop an image before applying CNN. I do not understand the above method of cropping.  I understand that it is attempting to crop the image but do not understand the negative value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does slice indexing work in numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55581540/how-does-slice-indexing-work-in-numpy-array)

Comment: Also helpful [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like NumPy advanced indexing, where you specify the indices for each axis, separated by commas. As for the negative, when indexing in Python a negative number indicates the index starts from the end and not the beginning. So, `60:-25` means *starting from index 60 and ending 25 indices from the end*.